# np.where and masked array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean-operations, masked-array

I'm working with masked arrays thanks to some of the help I've gotten on stackoverflow, but I'm running into a problem with the np.where evaluation of a masked array.

My masked array is:

```
m_pt0 = np.ma.masked_array([1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 7, 6, 5],
                           mask=[False, True, False, False,
                                 False, False, False, False])
```

And prints like this:

```
In [24]: print(m_pt0)
[1 -- 3 0 4 7 6 5]
```

And I'm looking for the index in m_pt0 where m_pt0 = 0, I would expect that

```
np.where(0 == m_pt0)
```

would return:

```
(array([3]))
```

However, despite the mask (or because of?), I instead get

```
(array([1, 3]),)
```

The entire point of using the mask is to avoid accessing indices that are "blank", so how can I use where (or another function) to only retrieve the indices that are unmasked and match my boolean criteria.

Comment: Did you try `ma.where()` from the `numpy.ma` submodule instead? Does it yield a different result?

Comment: Please show your full code. In an example that I put together everything works as expected.

Comment: `[1 -- 3 0 4 7 6 5]` is not  a valid numpy object. What's the real object that you're referring to?

Comment: @Kasramvd there, I fixed it for them.

Comment: @blubberdiblub has the same syntax that I'm using, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: As the documentations is stated, the package (masked array) ensures that masked entries are not used in computations. This is while the  `np.where()` performs a comparison not a computation. Try with another mask that filters some of your positive numbers then perform a function like `np.sum()`.

Comment: Masked array methods handle the computations correctly.  So do `np.ma` functions.  General `numpy` functions work if they delegate the work to the method.  Otherwise they will work with the unmasked `.data` attribute, and probably will be wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the masked variant of the `where()` function, otherwise it will return wrong or unwanted results for masked arrays. The same goes for other functions, like `polyfit()`.

I. e.:

```
In [2]: np.ma.where(0 == m_pt0)
Out[2]: (array([3]),)
```

Comment: This is the solution but read [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761425/np-where-and-masked-array?noredirect=1#comment74565203_43761425) for reason of such behavior.

Comment: @Kasramvd I don't think it's as clear-cut as that. `np.polyfit()` also doesn't work properly for masked arrays and that one does a computation, not a comparison.

Comment: Yes it does some computations. Although it still has some comparisons in it (with Degree of the fitting polynomial) but this does't make any difference I think this is kind of a bug in documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The equality test may create confusion.  The result is another masked array:

```
In [19]: 0 == m_pt0
Out[19]: 
masked_array(data = [False -- False True False False False False],
             mask = [False  True False False False False False False],
       fill_value = True)
```

A masked array has `.data` and `.mask` attributes.  `numpy` functions that aren't MA aware just see the `.data`:

```
In [20]: _.data
Out[20]: array([False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

`np.where` sees the 2 `True`, and returns

```
In [23]: np.where(0 == m_pt0)
Out[23]: (array([1, 3], dtype=int32),)
In [24]: np.where((0 == m_pt0).data)
Out[24]: (array([1, 3], dtype=int32),)
```

Where possible it is better to use the `np.ma` version of a function:

```
In [25]: np.ma.where(0 == m_pt0)
Out[25]: (array([3], dtype=int32),)
```

Looking at the code for `np.source(np.ma.where)` I see it does

```
if missing == 2:
    return filled(condition, 0).nonzero()
(plus lots of code for the 3 argument use)
```

That `filled` does:

```
In [27]: np.ma.filled((0 == m_pt0),0)
Out[27]: array([False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

`MA` functions often replace the masked values with something innocuous (0 in this case), or use `compressed` to remove them from consideration.

```
In [36]: m_pt0.compressed()
Out[36]: array([1, 3, 0, 4, 7, 6, 5])
In [37]: m_pt0.filled(100)
Out[37]: array([  1, 100,   3,   0,   4,   7,   6,   5])
```

A numpy function will work correctly on a MA if it delegates the work to the array's own method.

```
In [41]: np.nonzero(m_pt0)
Out[41]: (array([0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=int32),)
In [42]: m_pt0.nonzero()
Out[42]: (array([0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=int32),)
In [43]: np.where(m_pt0)
Out[43]: (array([0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=int32),)
```

`np.nonzero` delegates.  `np.where` does not.

---

The `repr` of a masked array shows the mask.  Its `str` just shows the masked data:

```
In [31]: m_pt0
Out[31]: 
masked_array(data = [1 -- 3 0 4 7 6 5],
             mask = [False  True False False False False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [32]: str(m_pt0)
Out[32]: '[1 -- 3 0 4 7 6 5]'
```